# Having max-width without causing vertical scrollbar to appear

Tags: css, width, scrollbar

I have these `CSS` rules for my `header`

```
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1250px;
```

Having those (in comparison to not having them) causes the vertical scroll bar to appear when the browser window is `< 1250px`.

What `CSS` should I have to let users with big screens see the `header` att `1250px` width, and the others with smaller width see the responsive header at their respective browser window size - without having the vertical scrollbar to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    #header {
        width: 1250px;
    }
}
```